# Parent component to get reference to any sub child components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular8

The goal is to understand how to get reference to any nested component. Here is the example with 4 nested components. A has B as child, B has C as its child and C has D as dynamic/run-time created child component. So questions are does Angular provide out of the box solution for:

**How A component can get reference to C component?**

**How A component can get reference to D component which is created at run-time?**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'A',
  template: `<B></B>`
})
export class A {}


@Component({
  selector: 'B',
  template: `<C></C>`
})
export class B {}



@Component({
  selector: 'C',
  template: `<div>C Component</div> <div #container></div>`
})
export class C implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('container')
  container: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private resolver:ComponentFactoryResolver){}
  ngOnInit() {
    const DFactory= this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(D);
    this.container.createComponent(DFactory);
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'D',
  template: `<div>D component</div>`
})
export class D{}
```

Comment: How A component can get reference to C component? Component B knows Component and should expose a property of the ViewChild Component C, so Component A should have a ViewChild binded to Component B. With the viewchildB componen A should can get the property of the viewchild C in the component B.

Comment: How A component can get reference to D component which is created at run-time? Start from the last question and add a new piublic properties in the component c which will be filled with the result of the `createComponent` function (return a ComponentRef  object). https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent

Comment: Not sure will work will quickly try this solution

Answer (score 0):

I make a stackblitz in order to show you what I was thinking. It's work but I am not sure what do you want exactly so hard to guess. But from A I can access to D. 
Like I told you :

**How A component can get reference to C component?**
Component B knows Component and should expose a property of the ViewChild Component C, so Component A should have a ViewChild binded to Component B. With the viewchildB componen A should can get the property of the viewchild C in the component B.

**How A component can get reference to D component which is created at run-time?**
Start from the last question and add a new piublic properties in the component c which will be filled with the result of the createComponent function (return a ComponentRef object). angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent

You can see the code here on the linked stackblitz. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abvno2

Comment: thank you for the proposition but I see some potential problems. Exposing reference to components via public properties is highly coupled approach. 

Is there a solution which will use '@ViewChildren' or '@ContentChildren' on a level of A component? 

This solution will be much more generic regardless of the actual components nesting structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, using @ViewChildren from grandparent component to query the child component won’t work. Since the child is wrapped by the parent he won’t be in the grandparent’s view DOM, therefore he won’t be available for querying. But we can try to query all the child components from the parent component.

Comment: humm maybe you are correct. But still it looks like really valid scenario. Found this example with  { descendants: true } but it does not work for me. You can experiment maybe to see maybe we have to wrap everything inside ng-content for it to work.
'@ContentChildren(MyInput, { descendants: true }) private inputComps: QueryList<MyInput>;'

Comment: What is your need exactly? do you want share informations between component ?